# What regular expression to parse a double quoted string followed by variable names?

Tags: php, regex, handlebars.js

I am making a helper for handlebars and want to parse something like this:

`"hello \"great\" friend" var1 var2`

The expression I have now works for things without double quotes inside the string:

`(?<=")[^"]*(?=")|(\w+)`

Thanks for any help!

The handlebars usage is `{{#gettext "Hello \"friend\" %s %s" var1 var2}}` where `#gettext` is my custom helper that consumes the string from the first `"` to before `}}`

**CLARIFICATION**

I do NOT want the `\` to show up upon rendering.
The expect output should be:

```
// Array of matches via preg_match_all
Hello "great" friend
var1
var2
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are you displaying the `\ ` because you have to type it in your string (to escape the double quote) or because it's actually going to be rendered (meaning the string you type is more like `\\\"` to get `\"`)?

Comment: I'll clarify up above for comments!

Comment: Updated a bunch of things that were unclear in the original text + addressed your questions

Answer (score 1):

I've made a different solution.

It's a little more flexible:

```
/"((?:\\"|[^"])+)"| (\w+)/g
```

This matches everything inside quotes or outside with a space before.

You can check on [this](https://regex101.com/r/dF4kF1/2) link for it in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$str = '"hello \"great\" friend" var1 var2';
$re = '/"(.+?)(?<!\\\\)"\h+(\w+)\h+(\w+)/';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
$matches[1] = stripslashes($matches[1]);
array_shift($matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello "great" friend
    [1] => var1
    [2] => var2
)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJ8hF4/1)

Comment: `$string = stripslashes($string);` vs the other str_replace should be fine right?

Comment: I'll mark your answer as good tomorrow if no one can make a regex for this without the throwaway entire string as arg 0 :)

Comment: For doing both matching and replacement one can use `preg_replace_callback` but that will also be a little bit of PHP code after regex

Comment: Oh the stripslashes isn't so bad. I just have to do an arbitrary array_shift to knock off the first arg, before doing array_shift again to get the real string out. Then I'm left an array with variable names which I need to actually loop through. Either way this works but not having that first match for everything would be ideal.

Comment: No I didn't mean anything in particular for `stripslashes`, I made an edit of what you are suggesting.

Comment: Did you update the regex? I'm still getting the first match on http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/. The output looks diff in edit but not regex

Comment: No regex is same but it has `stripslashes` and `array_shift` as per our dicsussion

Comment: Ah whoops missed that

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like ...

```
(^".*")|([ ]+([^ "]+))
```

**Explanation**

Matches greedily the longest prefix ending in a `"`. As this part is anchored to the start of the test string, this portion of the regex will never match again. Instead, the second portion gets all space-separated variable names.

**RegexDemo** [here](https://regex101.com/r/cI2nS8/6)

**Embedding in code**

Reformatting the output.
Regex and code work with multiple pairs of escaped quotes and arbitrary numbers of variables.

```
function postprocess ( &$item, $key ) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        $item = str_replace('\\"', '"', substr($item, 1, strlen($item)-2));
    }
    else {
        $item = substr($item, 1);
    }
}

$str = '"hello \"great\" friend of \"mine\"" var1 var2 var3 var4';
$re = '/(^"(.*)")|([ ]+([^ "]+))/';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];  # Array of complete matches
array_walk ($matches, 'postprocess');
print_r($matches);
```

This code has been tested on [writecodeonline.com](http://writecodeonline.com/php/).

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello "great" friend of mine
    [1] => var1
    [2] => var2
    [3] => var3
    [4] => var4
)
```